# MySQL sub query

Tags: mysql

```
UPDATE members 
    SET money=money+100 
WHERE username IN (    
                   SELECT username 
                     FROM forum
                  );
```

Lets say I wanted to give each of my members 100 money for each post in my forum. This query works but if one member has posted more than once, they only get 100. Could someone correct this query please?

Comment: Can you show the fields of both members and forum table?

Comment: 1) could you please inspect the answers, vote, and choose one. 2) And change the "IN" to "=" and eliminate the worktable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can go ahead and use that same subquery you used in the `where` clause in the `set` statement itself.

Like this

```
update members m 
    set money=money+100*(
                     select count(*) from forum f 
                        where f.username = m.username);
```

Comment: you can even replace f.username with 1 in the count :).. However can you edit your post to make it more readable, especially code formatting?

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand - your query will update all rows in `members` where the username exists in the `forum` table, not jsut the first match for each member.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE members 
    SET money=money+100 
WHERE username IN (
                   SELECT username 
                     FROM forum
                  );

to be

update m set money= money+ (count(f.username) *100 )
from member m 
inner join forum f on f.username = m.username

Answer (score -1):

I think you want this to be a dynamic query instead of updating the member table:

```
select username, count(username)*100 as money
from forum
group by username
order by username
```

if you must have it in the member table, then this query can be used in your update similar to the following:

```
update members m 
set money = (select count(username)*100 from forum f where f,username = m.username )
```

another issue here is when to do the update - this would best be done in a trigger so it would look more like a parameterized statement for only the current username in the current forum insert.

hth

Comment: That doesn't perform the update as requested. Perhaps you could expand on your answer?

Comment: You have to join this table with members table to update the money field in members

Comment: there is no where clause on the main query, wouldn't this just update every row in the members table?

Comment: yes - unless you place this code in a trigger, then you would add an additional and condition to apply to only this current row. (although i think this is a mutation condition - so it might be tricky)

Comment: @Randy. Trigger code to fix a query ?!?!? The most ridiculous answer I have read on StackOverflow.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA - notice this is an update - not a query. Notice that the intent is to persist some value in a table. The OP is attempting to update a table that should best be managed by triggers. Your shortsightedness is the type of thing that is hardest to take when contributing to this forum. - also notice that i gave two options that directly answered the question before i offered an alternative.

Comment: @Randy. If you read the manual, you will find an Update is a type of query.  No "persisting", just an update. No trigger necessary (that's my point).  No temp tables, no other tables necessary.  SO is for people seeking answers from professionals.    It is not a blog site for amateurs. Read the guidelines, we are encouraged to correct mistakes; I am just doing that.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA - if you read the dictionary, you would find that persist is the result of an update.  I humbly suggest you think about your own professionalism.

Comment: @Randy. In the database world we have had UPDATE for 40 years; we do not need to confuse things by using non-db terms.  OP is already aware that he is dealing with a simple single-statement UPDATE problem; not a persistence; not a trigger; not a multi-statement problem.  Do not ignore the comments of other posters, and that your answer is invalid for *many*, not one, reasons.  Professionals are correctable, they would have deleted your answer a long time ago.  Amateurs hang on to threads for dear life, just for the visibility.  Choose carefully.